# Eloquent's "with" doesn't return anything for one relationship, but does for other

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Member model in my Laravel application, and in the model:

```
public function active_memberships() {
    return $this->hasMany(MemberMembership::class, 'member_id', 'id')->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now());
    });
}

public function promo_code() {
    return $this->hasMany(MemberPromoCode::class, 'member_id', 'id');
}
```

Both the `member_memberships` and `member_promo_codes` tables have member_id as a foreign key. However, if I do this:

```
$member = Member::with(['active_memberships','promo_code'])->find($id);
```

I get the `active_memberships` array in `$member`, but not `promo_code`.

So, `$member['active_memberships']` prints out an array., but `$member['promo_code']` gives an error:

```
Undefined index: promo_code
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a column by chance with a name `promo_code` in `members` table?

Comment: I do not. If it helps, the `member_promo_codes` has another foreign key, `promo_code_id`, that connects it to a table called `promo_codes`. But I don't see how that could affect this.

Comment: _that connects it to a table called `promo_codes`_ Use `with(['active_memberships','promo_codes'])` then (notice the **s**)

Comment: Nah, that shouldn't be an issue. Just to debug, try this: `$member = Member::with('promo_code')->find($id);` and see if you get `$member['promo_code']` ?

Comment: @cbaconnier what did you say? you are saying using 's' will resolve the issue? :)

Comment: @Learner In that query I see the promo_code array! What do you think might be the explanation? Is my syntax incorrect for having multiple `with`s?

Comment: @jovan, no your with is OK, try the solution I provided below as an answer, see if that works

Comment: @Learner Nevermind, I guess my empty stomach gives me a melted brain :(

Comment: @cbaconnier cool

Comment: @jovan, i take it my solution worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your relationship methods to these:

```
public function active_memberships() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\MemberMembership', 'member_id')->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now());
    });
}

public function promo_code() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\MemberPromoCode', 'member_id');
}
```

You don't need to pass the third parameter as `id` because that is by default and try to give the relation using the namespace as that is the most basic way to define relations.

See if Controller query works then?